# Strange behavior: latex-suite, alt-key macros, adding <++>. How can I disable this?

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I’m using vim with the latex-suite plugin, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. (I installed the plugin through the Ubuntu package manager, i.e., through `sudo apt install vim-latexsuite`, then followed the documentation [here](https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html).)

Suppose `_` represents where my cursor is. I have `sample.tex` open, with these contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
_
\end{document}
```

I type `((`, and the text is changed into

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\left(_ \right)<++>
\end{document}
```

I want to see this instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
((_
\end{document}
```

According to the documentation [here](https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/altkey-mappings.html) and [here](https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-suite-maps.html#customize-alt-key-maps), this is supposed to be associated with the `<Alt-L>` key combination (which I’m not using). How do I disable whatever it’s doing?

Comment: I am not sure if you have already heard of other plugins for vim and latex, but I'd recommend [__vimtex__](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) over vim-latex anytime. For one, vimtex does not automatically insert `\left(` and `\right)` on its own.

Comment: I hadn’t heard of it! Thank you, I’ll check it out!